# How to convert YUV data to CVPixelBufferRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit, cvpixelbuffer

I have the Yuv data below :

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) int chromaWidth;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) int chromaHeight;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) const uint8_t *dataY;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) const uint8_t *dataU;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) const uint8_t *dataV;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) int strideY;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) int strideU;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) int strideV;
```

Now how to convert it to `CVPixelBufferRef`?